# Cannot create account using EOSJS 16: Permissions Error

Tags: eosjs

I know EOSJS 16 is deprecated, but I want to know how to solve this following error in it.

```
  var Eos = require('eosjs');

// Default configuration
var config = {
  chainId: 'CID', // 32 byte (64 char) hex string
  keyProvider: 'KPD',
  httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8888',
  expireInSeconds: 60,
  broadcast: true,
  verbose: false, // API activity
  sign: true
};

var eos = Eos(config);

eos.transaction(tr => {
    tr.newaccount({
      creator: 'accountadmin',
      name: 'testaccount',
      owner: 'PB1',
      active: 'PB2'
    });
    tr.buyrambytes({
      payer: 't1',
      receiver: 'testaccount',
      bytes: 1024 * 3
    });
    tr.delegatebw({
      from: 't1',
      receiver: 'testaccount',
      stake_net_quantity: '1.0000 SGHX',
      stake_cpu_quantity: '1.0000 SGHX',
      transfer: 0
    });
  }).then(function (result) {
          console.log("here??");
    console.log(result);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
```

Above is the reproducable example of my code.

I have created two wallets, testaccount-owner and testaccount-active. And used their public keys here. I want to create another account 'testaccount' using an accountadmin I created, but whenever I run this script I get an error saying

> Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared
>   authorizations","details":[{"message":"transaction declares authority
>   '{\"actor\":\"accountadmin\",\"permission\":\"active\"

To do this in the command line I would have simply included the flag -p accountadmin@active, but I can't figure out where to give the authority here.

Answer (score 0):

```
eos.transaction(tr => {
    tr.newaccount({
      creator: 'accountadmin',
      name: 'testaccount',
      owner: 'PB1',
      active: 'PB2'
    });
    tr.buyrambytes({
      payer: 't1',
      receiver: 'testaccount',
      bytes: 1024 * 3
    });
    tr.delegatebw({
      from: 't1',
      receiver: 'testaccount',
      stake_net_quantity: '1.0000 SGHX',
      stake_cpu_quantity: '1.0000 SGHX',
      transfer: 0
    });
  }, {keyProvider: "Your private key"})
```